# How do I remove the confirmation alert when choosing Silent mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

SG2 with ICS 4.0.4: When I long press the power button and choose Silent mode, I get a confirmation alert stating that "Silent mode will be enabled".Then, I get to choose between "OK" or "Cancel", like I'm some clumsy child making bad decisions...

After long pressing the power button, and chosing Silent mode, I think that is one step too many, and it annoys me to have to confirm what I already confirmed that I wanted to do.

**How do I remove the confirmation box ?**

In a perfect world, I wouldn't have to go trough that extra step, and instead I'd just get a confirmation stating : "Silent mode enabled" or something in that line.

Comment: Have you considered using a widget like Widgetsoid so you have one tap access to toggle silent / normal modes?

Comment: Running Stock ROM?

Comment: This is not standard android behavior, it must be something added in TouchWiz or if you used custom ROM. In my stock Galaxy Nexus, toggling silent mode does not have any additional confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be baked in to the stock ROM you are using.

There are widgets, like [silentwidget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guywmustang.silentwidget) which will let you toggle the silent mode without using the power button method, although this requires you to go to the launcher to do this - to get around this, have a look at a multitasking app like [PowerStrip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.intuitit.android.p.powerstrip) which will allow you to launch apps, see widgets and more from anywhere on your device without having to go back to the launcher.

Comment: In the new update this problem is luckily fixed. Additionally, you can now choose between silent, vibrate and sound. Whoever thought of it: Thank you!